# How to use extended generics in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm working on a solo project (personal training in server-side dart) where I would like to be able to get already deserialized response from my dio based api service.
(https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

It is not yet written but, for example, the usage could be:

```
var alreadyDeserializedObject = (await ApiService.request<SerializableType>("GET", "URL")).data
```

But I'm stuck with the deserialization part at the moment, here is what I have in VS code :

[Problematic code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew3oS.png)

I don't understand why at line 14 I can't use the `Serializable.fromJson` constructor with the generic type `T extends Serializable` ?

Could you please explain to me why it is not possible, and maybe what I could do instead to achieve it?

Comment: Static members(and constructors) are not inherited. Therefore, your `T` generic might not have a `fromJson` constructor available and cannot be called safely. The linked duplicate is not the *exact* same problem as your, but it may be treated as such.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I accepted the duplicate post cause it is indeed linked to my issue.